# How to center certain fields Wordpress plug-in contact form 7?

Tags: css, wordpress

I managed to align the form to the center of the page but the 'Acceptance Button' below the text area is still aligned to the left. How can I center that acceptance checkbox?

```
.wpcf7 input[type=text], .wpcf7 input[type=email], .wpcf7 input[type=password] {
    width:500px;
    text-align: left;
}

.wpcf7 label {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: left;
}


.wpcf7 textarea {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: left;
}


div.wpcf7 {
text-align: center;

}
```

Below you will see an image. I'm looking for moving the accept checkbox below the submit button.

[image]

Comment: Please show the generated HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your html code generate like this, Then you should be try

Hope this help.

Let me know further clearification

```css
 .wpcf7 span.wpcf7-form-control {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpcf7">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox">
 <span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-948[]" value="Accept">
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Accept</span>
 </span>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below please.
I used something similar in the past but I can't double check if it is 100% correct right now.

```
.wpcf7 input[type="acceptance"],
.wpcf7-list-item-label {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `acceptance`should be typed without the ""

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there are no differences between using (or not using) speech marks on your input type. It is just a matter of user preference. See the following snippet, if you remove the speech marks, the button will remain exactly the same. https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_attselector_form